# CSS approach to image-gallery baseline on Cargocollective

Tags: html, css

I am building a website on Cargocollective.
I want to change the baseline to top of the image gallery. (Now based on baseline)

When I watch the source through Google inspector, I can find the code right this
[image]

but I can't find that css code in cargocollective CSS editing window,
and I don't know how I can approach to that.

help me!

- and I want to know make image full to the square. (to be no blank in the square, even if the image is cut off somewhat)
  How can I ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using flexbox, wich means items are at the center of the height, if you want to change the baseline you would have to change the height of a row.

Or you could use flex start / flex end to set all images top or bottom

> and I want to know make image full to the square

For this you want to research things like cover or contain
src (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

Make the widht and height like 200px x 200px and make the child as the background. then use cover/contain